# How to find x values the turning points of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Say as an example I have the polynomial

> $$ y = ax^2 + bx^4.$$

How would I find the $x$ values of the turning points?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What are the turning points?

Comment: Turning points are the points where a polynomial starts to move down after moving up, or vice versa.

Comment: I know them as local extrema (and it's not only a terminology for polynomials).

Answer (score 1):

To find the turning points (stationary points) we look for the stationary points first, and then find the classification of the points.

For your problem
$$
y = ax^2 + bx^4
$$
we find the stationary points
$$
y' = 2ax + 4bx^3 = 0 = 2(a + 2bx^2)x
$$
so we have 3 points of interest

- $x = 0$
- $x = \pm \sqrt{-\frac{a}{2b}}$

To find the classification we take the second derivative
$$
y'' = 2a + 12bx^2
$$
for $x=0$ we have
$$
y'' = 2a
$$
and for $x = \pm \sqrt{-\frac{a}{2b}}$ 
we have
$$
y'' = 2a + 12b\left(-\frac{a}{2b}\right) = 2a -6a = -4a
$$
so depending on sign of $a$, we will find out what the points are, for example 
$ a > 0$ we have

- $x=0 \implies \text{minimum}$
- $x = \pm \sqrt{-\frac{a}{2b}} \implies \text{maximum}$

If $a=0$ then we have inflexion points.